# Allow OIDC Users to use clientCredentials to gain programmatic access to trusted APIs

Tags: identityserver4

What is the correct way to provide users with programmatic access to APIs?

I have an application composed of many services (all trusted services, within the same domain, not external applications), and identity service in the same domain.
I would like to allow a user to user a set of credentials to gain access to any of the APIs I provide.

Is it reasonable to think of a user as a client in this case, and use clientCredentials flow to get a token that will be passed to the target API? specifically, is it a good idea automatically assign a clientId and a clientSecret to every user in my system, and allow all users to use clientCredentials flow to request an access token? the access token would then contain all user's claims. If this is a reasonable approach, is there any way to remove the "client_" prefix from the added claims? or is that a bad idea?

This was originally asked here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1877

Comment: [A user is not a client](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/intro/terminology.html).

Comment: When a writes code to access an API, that code becomes a client.

Comment: meant to say "when a user writes...". the idea is to have a "client" that has the same claims as a user, to allow the user to to access the API through code with only one set of credentials.

Comment: But a user is still not a client - a client is a piece of software for accessing your protected resources. You are talking about a user needing to have access to all your APIs, so why not protect your APIs in the normal way (maybe with roles, maybe with a scope ...) and have a user validate themselves against your identity server and if they have the correct role then they can access your API. Or maybe the clients those users access all request tokens of a particular scope. I'm struggling to see why you can just use 'normal' identity server grant/flows.

Comment: I think you missed my point, I want "a piece of software" to have the same set of permissions as a user. e.g. when I use AWS, I can create a user and give it some permissions. then I can give this user a set of credentials (username and password) to login to AWS console to manage resources. I can also generate API keys (id and secret) for the same user to access the AWS APIs using a piece of software. The user making changes through the console and the software accessing the APIs will have the same set of claims.

Comment: No I understand what you are saying, but in both your cases it is still the user who is providing the credentials. Whether it is an id and secret, or username and password, it is the user credentials being authenticated. Both of those cases are handled natively using standard identity server flows, without trying to "think of a user as a client". ClientCredentials flow is more suitable for machine-to-machine authorization, where the client is confidential. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452027/why-use-client-credentials-flow or https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-9 may help

Comment: Thank you for continuing the discussion. I think I understand what you mean. I think what I intended to say/do was the same thing but didn't make it quite clear in the question. I want to issue user credentials to each user of the system for when they sign into my application via a browser and want to use my UI. but when they need to write a custom application (client) to access my APIs directly, I need to issue a set a client credentials to them to authenticate their application with the API.